# How to write algebra formulas in android xml

Tags: android

Here is an example

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.entertainment.algebra_calculator_1

I just wanted to know how the formulas are written in xml like 1/x, superscripts, subscripts.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for super script

```
TextView mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
mTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("10<sup>3</sup>"));
```

For sub script

```
TextView mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
mTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("A<sub>2</sub>"));
```